# Maven builds on file changes

Tags: java, windows, maven, build-process, maven-3

Is there anything already out there that would help with either / both of following?

- Perform a Maven install when a file within that module changes
- Perform a Maven install on the module *and its dependencies **if** they have changed*

I'm pretty sure I've heard of a Maven option to build dependencies as well but struggling to find anything from Googling...

Perhaps this isn't going to be Maven specific but instead involve a file watching tool that is OS specific, if so I would be interested in hearing about tools for Windows (XP).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though the answer comes late, I was looking for the same thing and I found https://github.com/rzymek/watcher-maven-plugin. Maybe someone else will be looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I tried @Adrian's solution, but I couldn't get it working.

I found this maven package, https://github.com/fizzed/maven-plugins#watcher-fizzed-watcher-maven-plugin, that will watch for file changes, and I was able to get it working pretty quickly.

Answer (score -2):

To building a module and its dependencies, use:
    mvn -pl :module -amd

Automated builds are usually triggered from a version system like subversion or git.
Then you can use continuous integration tools like Jenkins.

There's also mvn reactor:make-scm-changes, which detects what modules have local changes vs. the configured scm system.

Comment: However, I think -pl only works for a multi module project. It seems you cannot specify a sibling project, only child projects.

Comment: Thanks for the `amd` tip...that was what I was thinking of. However we already have CI builds triggered from SCM polling, what I am interested in is local builds triggered by local file changes. To put this into context; I have web resources (e.g. JS templates) that require compilation performed by a Maven build, I want to automate the compilation step for development ease / speed.

Comment: `Automated builds are usually triggered from a version system like subversion or git.`. Op stated he wants this done on file change. VCS will do this post-commit or post-push.